# How to count most frequent string within an array of strings?

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers, struct

I need to build a function that returns the most frequent sourceIP (and then Destination IP) within an array of structs. This is my structure.

```
typedef  enum { IN_IN, IN_OUT, OUT_IN} Direction;
typedef enum { IGMP, TCP, UDP} Protocol;
typedef  unsigned  int Count;
#define NUM 6
typedef struct {
    long long timestamp;
    Direction direction;
    char sourceIP[16];
    char destIP[16];
    Protocol protocol;
    unsigned int port;
    Count bytes;
}Packet;
```

I need to implement a function which receives the size of the array, an array type *Packet* and returns the most frequent IP source address within an array of structs. Here is my STRUCT array:

```
Packet packetsarray[NUM] = {
            {42069, IN_OUT, "192.100.200.2", "192.10.0.6", TCP, 30, 256 },
            {666, OUT_IN, "148.201.196.208", "148.201.196.1", UDP, 80,666},
            {1002, IN_IN, "192.100.200.2", "10.10.0.6", IGMP, 30, 256 },
            {1002, IN_OUT, "192.100.200.2", "10.10.0.6", IGMP, 30, 256 },
            {1002, OUT_IN, "192.100.200.2", "10.10.0.6", IGMP, 30, 256 },
            {1002, IN_OUT, "192.100.200.2", "10.10.0.6", IGMP, 30, 256 }};
```

However my teacher explicitly states **do the operation without using any brackets, ONLY using pointer arithmetrics** this is what I have so far for my function:

```
void CountDirections(Packet packets[], int N, int *c1, int *c2, int *c3)
{
    *c1 = 0;
    *c2 = 0;
    *c3 = 0;
    Packet *packetpointer = packets;
    Packet *packetpointer2 = packets;
    packetpointer2++;
    int i, maxcount = 0, count = 0;
    char word[16];
    for (i= 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if(packetpointer->direction == IN_OUT)
            *c2 += 1;
        else if(packetpointer->direction == OUT_IN)
            *c3 += 1;
        else if (packetpointer->direction == IN_IN)
            *c1 += 1;
        packetpointer++;
    }
    packetpointer = packets;
    for (i= 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        strcpy(word, packetpointer->sourceIP);
        printf("%s\n", word);
        packetpointer++;
    }

}
```

I have **NO CLUE** how to find the most frequent SourceIP within the array of structs without using brackets [] a friend told me to use a MODE algorithm but I don't know how to implement it using pointers only. Please help.

Comment: Does "_using pointer arithmetrics_" mean that your teacher wants the `Packet`s to be in a linked list?

Comment: no, he wants to use packet* packets instead of packets[] and use pointer arithmetic to specify offset instead of packet[N]

Comment: Ok, then replace `Packet packets[]` with `Packet *packets` and you're done. `packets[index]` is the same as `*(packets + index)` but why anyone would prefer _that_ is a mystery.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the code where you try to count occurence of IP addresses

Comment: first, i would use numbers, not strings for IP addresses (32bit IP address fits into unsigned int). there should be a function to convert these strings to numbers. To find the most frequent IP, the thing that comes to my mind is to make an array of only source IP addresses, sort this array, then count how many times each one appear (you need to sort it so that all equal values appear one after another). there is a snippet here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/frequent-element-array/. An example with strings is here: https://www.javatpoint.com/program-to-find-the-most-repeated-word-in-a-text-file

Comment: Anyway... `qsort` is your friend